# Sharing proxy-cache among multiple user groups

Tags: transparent-proxy

Here is what I am trying to do. I have two different VLANs, each using their own Squid proxy-caches. Now I want to set up a single proxy-cache which both VLANs use. The catch is I don't want them to share the cache for security purposes. Is it possible to provide isolation in this way? I am willing to use some other proxy-cache which provides this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run as many instances of Squid (or any proxy) on the one box as you're machines resources will allow. If you have 2 separate configs and [`cache_dir`](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/cache_dir/)'s for each they will remain functionally separate. Plumb each VLAN into the box and have squid1 listening on each VLAN1 and squid2 listening on VLAN2